# application.handlebars template isn't rendered (as it should be by default)

Tags: ember.js, padrino

my goal is a simple js mvc appliction.

i'm using padrino, and trying to add ember.js. also, i switched to asset pipeline in this project, just for simplicity.

i have a problem with rendering a default *application.handlebars* template. it isn't rendered. i know, that its content should be rendered by default. but, when i start the server, i don't see anything by now.

in **./templates/application.handlebars**:

```
<div id="container">
  <h1>Raffler</h1>
</div>
```

in **./application.js**:

```
//= require lib/jquery
//= require lib/jquery-ujs
//= require lib/handlebars
//= require lib/ember
//= require_self
//= require raffler

Raffler = Ember.Application.create();
```

in **./rafler.js**

```
//= require ./store
//= require_tree ./models
//= require_tree ./controllers
//= require_tree ./views
//= require_tree ./helpers
//= require_tree ./templates
//= require ./router
//= require_tree ./routes
//= require_self
```

in **./controllers/application_controller.coffee**

```
Raffler.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend()
```

in **./routes/application_routes.coffee**

```
Raffler.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend()
```

in **router.coffee**

```
Raffler.Router.map ->
```

all js files, is compiled in one, you know (/assets/application.js)

what could it be?

Comment: Have you tried removing the Router? if you don't have any routes defined I guess you don't need to specify one at all.

Comment: Make sure `Ember.TEMPLATES` includes the application template (key: application)

Comment: thanks, guys! now i'm mastering templates with grunt (to precompile). it works! (really, i don't know that they need to be precompiled :(.)